# HorizontalScrollView "Style" not working on 1.6 or 2.1?

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I have a test version of my app that uses a HorizontalScrollView.

When I run it on a 2.33 Emulator, the "Style", glowing on each end of the
scrolling, and the scroll bar appearing, then disappearing, works fine, but
when I load the same .APK on a 1.6 Emulator, the "Style" mostly stops
working.  The scroll bar is always on, and there is no glowing when you
scroll to either end, but the functionality works.

I know you can't totally count on the Emulator working right,
but I'd like it to work on 1.6.

The docs say that HorizontalScrollView was added in API Level 3,
which is before 1.6, so in theory it should work fine.

No Styles are defined for the app, and I noticed that the HorizontalScrollView
has a certain "Style" listed.

Just in case, here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hscrollview"
        android:background="#ee1a1a1a"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/hsvgallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

   </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I loaded the test app on a G1 with 1.6 and the same thing happens
the scroll bar stays on, and no "glow" at either end of scrolling,
but it does "work", I'll just have to deal with it I guess..

Comment: Do you really need to make your app run on 1.6 devices? They are not even listed anymore on market share in android developers...

Comment: There are still a small percentage of people who are using my app that have 1.6.  Plus, I tried it on a 2.1 Emulator and the same thing happens, but on 2.33 or 2.34 it's fine.